# How do I make signOut Google+ in onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I'm doing Sign In with Google+ that leads to the Navigation.activity. Ive follow the instruction on Google developer but I only took signIn method(Success) but now im stuck at navigation.activity. How do i make logout from navigationItemSelected?

What is the problem : 
Google plus signIn in Main Activity but need to Logout from Navigation Activity...

TY for helping

```
  else if (id == R.id.logout) {

  }
```

This is my onResult

```
@Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
```

It will call hideprogress and handleSignInResult method..

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        // Signed out
    }
}



private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Signing Out Users and Disconnecting Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect#sign_out_users) official link to perform SignOut and Revoke Access operation

**Singout**

```
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

**Disconnect account**

```
private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I've update the question showing the OnResult sir :)

Comment: I am talking about `onResult(Status status)` which is inside of Signout and revoke methods

Comment: oh I didnt put anything . hmm

Comment: If so, how do I called it from the HomeActivity(where user can logout)

Comment: call `signOut()` and `revokeAccess()` when logout button is clicked like this `else if (id == R.id.logout) {
signOut(); revokeAccess();
  }`

Comment: Im sorry to ask this. When i create those method in new activity. What do i need to put insid onResult? ps Im totally new in this

Comment: check what is the result of that request like this `status.isSuccess()` , whether it returns true or false.

Comment: if (status.isSuccess()) {

                            
                            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,Main.class);

                            startActivity(intent);

    }
 Like this? T_T